# Unable to install Julia packages by Pkg.add("something")

Tags: windows, cmd, package, julia

According to [this site](https://juliastats.org/Distributions.jl/stable/starting/), we can install Julia package by putting the following command on the shell:

```
Pkg.add("Distributions")
```

However, I get the error below:

```
(@v1.6) pkg> Pkg.add("Distributions")
ERROR: Could not determine command
```

What is wrong.
I'm using Windows10 and the shell is Command Prompt.

Any information would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you're running it from the wrong mode.

The approach you are using is based on package `Pkg` (some kind of package for packages), therefore you have to run it like a normal code.

```
julia> using Pkg
julia> Pkg.add("your_package")
```

However, in your snippet you're trying to use it from package mode, which is enabled by pressing `]` in REPL. This mode is actually more convenient and AFAIK more preferable than using Pkg. So instead you could do this:

```
julia> ] # you don't have to press enter
pkg> add your_package
```

You can read about package mode [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Pkg/).

Answer (score 3):

Use REPL, enter package mode by typing `]` (the prompt `(@v1.6) pkg>` shows you already did that), then just type :

```
add "Distributions"
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be just `add Distributions` (without the double quotes)?

Comment: @BenoitPasquier actually both are valid.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. I was using pkg mode and it seems to be more preferable than using Pkg.add() function . I'd like to keep going with it.